# How do I get Html5 audio to play sound on click? (ogg for browsers like Firefox and mp3 for browsers like chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio

How do I get Html5 audio to play sound on click? (ogg for browsers like Firefox and mp3 for browsers like chrome)

So far onclick I can change to a single filetype but I can't get it to have a backup option like you do on a normal html5 audio declaration i.e.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>How do i call the javascript function and get it to play .ogg if can't play .mp3?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="Mp3Me" autoplay autobuffer controls>
  <source src="Piano.mp3">
</audio>

<a href="javascript:GuitarTrack()">Guitar</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GuitarTrack(){
var Mp3Me= document.getElementById('Mp3Me');
Mp3Me.src = "Guitar.mp3";
Mp3Me.src = "Guitar.ogg";
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating only one `<source>` element, you have to either create another `<source>` element in HTML or create one using JavaScript.

1. Creating second element using HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/PVqvC/

   ```
   <audio id="Mp3Me" autoplay autobuffer controls>
   <source src="Piano.mp3">
   <source src="Piano.ogg">
   </audio>
   <a href="javascript:GuitarTrack();">Guitar</a>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function GuitarTrack(){
       var Mp3Me= document.getElementById('Mp3Me');
       Mp3Me.children[0].src = "Guitar.mp3";
       Mp3Me.children[1].src = "Guitar.ogg";
       Mp3Me.load();
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Creating second element using JS. http://jsfiddle.net/MBvsC/1/

   ```
   <audio id="Mp3Me" autoplay autobuffer controls>
   <source src="Piano.mp3">
   </audio>
   <a href="javascript:GuitarTrack();">Guitar</a>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function GuitarTrack(){
       var Mp3Me= document.getElementById('Mp3Me').getElementsByTagName('source');

       if(Mp3Me.length > 1) { //there are 2 elements
           Mp3Me[0].src = "Guitar.mp3";
           Mp3Me[1].src = "Guitar.ogg";
       }
       if(Mp3Me.length == 1) { //only one element, so we need to create the second one
           Mp3Me[0].src = "Guitar.mp3"; //changes existing element

           var node = document.getElementById('Mp3Me');
           var newelem = document.createElement('source');
           newelem.setAttribute('src', 'Guitar.ogg');
           node.appendChild(newelem); //creating new element with appropriate src                         
       }
       Mp3Me.load();
   }
   </script>
   ```

As you can see, the first method is a lot shorter and cleaner, so if you can use it - use it. If you have any further questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: Couldn't manage to get the above code to work?

I've added active .ogg and .mp3 (free to use piano track) to your jsfiddle code above, to show it not working.

First:http://jsfiddle.net/PVqvC/2/
Second:http://jsfiddle.net/MBvsC/4/

Comment: Sorry, in both cases you have to use `load()` method. I've edited my answer and updated the fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/MBvsC/6/ http://jsfiddle.net/PVqvC/3/

Comment: Thanks second version works perfectly, one question, do you know why no controls(play,pause,time seek etc) show up when tried in firefox  but they do in Chrome when using Jsfiddle above?

Comment: Probably because `src` in HTML (before change) are not found on fiddle's servers. It will work on your website though (if you add existing file to the `src` parameter). You can test it by replacing `piano.mp3` and `piano.ogg` by your external links on fiddle.