# click image hear sound in browser

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a website at present.

There many sites/sources I have and could go to for doing what I want. But their ways/steps aren't working for me.

I have the following situation:

I have 2 cols in Dreamweaver. 
1 for images and the right col for text.

I want the user to click on the image and hear the audio of the person in the picture. 
No players or other pages opening. Click image and hear audio that's it.

Can this be done. As the current and only example seems to leave me uncertain:

http://www.it-student.org.uk/playsound/playsounds.php

I set it up as it asks nothing happens no sound.

```
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script> 
  function EvalSound(soundobj) { 
    var thissound= eval("document."+soundobj); 
    thissound.Play();
  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <embed src="hannbil smith.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
   <a href="#" onClick="EvalSound('sound1')"><img src="han cast.jpg""></a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hi John. Welcome to SO. At least show what you have tried - post code and link to for example a jsfiddle.net - if not forget getting any help

Comment: My advice would be to stop what you're doing, and get more familiar with the technologies you're trying to use. It's fairly easy to learn the basics of HTML & CSS. Then move on to JavaScript. Its best to learn it now, so you're better-armed in the future.

Comment: Your embed is not closed and the url in the src contains spaces

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using jQuery

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/e9Vcy/14/)

```
var manifest = [
    {id:"waiting", src:"http://stardotserver.co.uk/waiting2.ogg"}  
]
var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue()
preload.installPlugin(createjs.Sound)
preload.loadManifest(manifest)

$('img').on('click',function() {
    createjs.Sound.play("waiting", createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE, 0, 0, -1, .5)
});
```

Comment: thx for all the help. html, css and java are on top of my list. But Im doing the site for a course. This what ive my heart set on adding to spice up the text/images main content where the profiles pages are.

Comment: I went onto your site http://www.it-student.org.uk/playsound/playsounds.php# this page, and when you click the image the sound plays fine. Ensure you have allowed 'runtime' to execute when prompted.

Comment: thx for all the help. based on the link above I used that example. this is code for it. the site is live. so cant post a link. here is the code...                 <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
 function EvalSound(soundobj) {
 var thissound= eval("document."+soundobj);
 thissound.Play();
 }
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<embed src="hannbil smith.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1"
 enablejavascript="true">

<a href="#" onClick="EvalSound('sound1')"><img src="han cast.jpg""></a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: The code you have posted runs a function `EvalSound` when clicked.

Comment: the code posted above I have no idea what to do with it. where do I add it in dreamweaver to make it work?

Comment: You embed code has an error in the `src` You are not allowed spaces `<embed src="hannbil smith.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1" enablejavascript="true">` in the src attribute `src="hannbil smith.mp3"` you must remove the spaces and use the file name exactly as it is named with the correct file path.

Comment: ive got an extended issue the click on image sound plays but. my page has 2 div area's. leftcol pics and rightcol txt. there area div area's inside that the main div area for leftcol. to hold the pics. I have in a separate div's for the pics. and same for txt. so same height for pic and text div. but issue is with div/css. The code posted doesn't work with my coding. viewing site via external through dreamweaver shows a 404 error in explorer. I have a new site folder set up. but it going to other site folder for rooting. it seems like more issues than needs be any help.

Comment: the code works in a table in cs5 dw. but with my temp set-up for site to keep the look the same. ive used css, div. For formatting and positioning. in regards to the sound not playing.im getting ftp error so wont load page externally. basically the whole sites a mess.ive had several started versions of the site saved with different site names. but the one im using now is temp with link to other failed site attempts. new folder new set-up. and still loads of issues. can help re-think this.

Comment: I would avoid dreameweaver. It bloats your code by adding in it's own. I would stick with a simple text editor like notepad++ or sublime and work alongside tutorials when ever you need a hand. Don't depend on dreamweaver for any help as it isn't a good idea.

Comment: im doing a site for the end of a course. ive down all assignments in dw cs5 & fl cs5. so I need to use dream cant use anything else. with using div element and css applied. how can I use the code presented for the audio to work. as its not. I know zero about coding. I have 3 pages. 1 has 5 images that audio to be linked to and code to play audio. and 2 images on next page. 4 for images on last page. where do I place code as presented. in the html structure for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You AT LEAST need to close the embed tag and remove spaces from the URL.
Also EVAL is EVIL. Lastly return false from the onclick

I gave it an ID and use getElementById

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script> 
  function evalSound(soundobj) { 
    var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj); 
    thissound.Play();
    return false;
  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <embed src="hannbil%20smith.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 name="sound1" id="sound1" enablejavascript="true" />
   <a href="#" onclick="return evalSound('sound1')"><img src="han%20cast.jpg""></a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: ill post the direct link to the page and ask the question. id like to know where in the code aspect of my site. can I put code into the html to allow the visitor viewing my site to click on the image and hear sound. I don't want that. Please tell what code is there that I can place into the html code in my site to allow click on image hear sound and no players, or anything. There is suggestion above but can get it to work anymore. http://theateam.freeiz.com/csat_creator/cast_creator.html here is the link to the page. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317318/how-do-i-get-html5-audio-to-play-sound-on-click-ogg-for-browsers-like-firefox

Comment: to be 100% honest nothing ive input is working for embedding or anyo other way with these scripts above. ive stated im no expert on css, java or any coding. so ive run out ideas. in reference to image click and hear sound or sound play in browser in quicktime format nothing works.

Comment: the only way it works is. select image and and link sound to it. but it opens another browser and dont want it doing that. as jumping back and forward to put off any visitor. any ideas?

Comment: If that is working, target a hidden iframe: `<iframe name="hiddenframe" style="display:none"></iframe>`

Comment: http://theateam.freeiz.com/csat_creator/cast_creator.html if you look at mysite ive inside a page container with 2 col's. 1 for images and text in right col. all images have their own DIV holders. i cant use a table layout as its for a final site course. the college wont allow tables for layout. you all have posted helpful examples but where in the html code in the examples do i add code. as its complicated using divs but easy with tables. can i attach code to my image to play sound. if so where does it go based on my coded page a above.